# How to convert a monolithic CSV String into a List<String>?

Tags: java, string, csv, arraylist

I have a CSV stored in a String:

```
Abc, Def, Ghi, Jkl, Mno[CR|LF]
Abc, Def, Ghi, Jkl, Mno[CR|LF]
Abc, Def, Ghi, Jkl, Mno[CR|LF]
Abc, Def, Ghi, Jkl, Mno[CR|LF]
```

When I open the file in Notepad++ and use "`Show All Characters`" I see the newline character at the end of each line represented by the `[CR|LF]` notation I indicated above.

How do convert this monolithic String into a `List<String>` where each line above represents a separate String in the `List` but without the `[CR|LF]` characters?

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be as simple as:

```
String allData /* = readCSVFromFile() */;
String[] rows = allData.split("\r\n");
List<String> rowList = Arrays.asList(rows);
```

Comment: Just a note, my answer assumes that `[CR|LF]` means always CR followed by LF.  If that's not the case and it could instead contain either or both, you could use a more complex regex like `.split("[\r|\n]+")`

Answer (score 1):

Use a `BufferedReader`. Something like this:

```
List<String> rows = new ArrayList<String>();
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.csv"));
String line = null;
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null)
{
    rows.add(line);
}
```

Comment: It seems like the file's contents are in a `String`, so alternatively you could use a `StringReader` instead of `FileReader`.

Comment: @Mark: He says: "When I open it with Notepad++"